# How to reset Vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a strange error in my Vue component. I've created the index page, updated the app.js and created a new component. I've also cleared my cache, and restated the npm watch. I keep getting the same error, Vue is looking at the wrong component. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Here is my code in case I've missed something.

**index** :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<h1> Goals</h1>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container">

    <goals></goals>

</div>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

**app.js file :**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('goals',
  require('./components/Goals.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**component Goal.vue :**

```
    <template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card card-default">
                    <div class="card-header">Goals</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        This is the goals example
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and the error :

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

If I swap the view with the News component all works well, but the min I change it the view crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
<router-view>
    <goals></goals>
</router-view>

</div>
```

Comment: you didnt use <router-view> tag in blade

Comment: That's because he doesn't use Vue Router..?

Answer (score 1):

try running `php artisan view:clear` you might have a cached view.

Answer (score 1):

From your snippets above, the code references **goals** whereas the filename is **Goal.vue** i.e. non-plural. Try changing the filenanme to **Goals.vue**